# Java iText PDF Internal Links

Tags: java, itext

I created internal links using named destinations.  The links work as expected when viewing the PDF in Foxit PhantomPDF but not Adobe Reader XI.  Why?

Unfortunately, I can not show you the PDF file because it is defense related.

I was able to make the links work as expected in Adobe Reader by changing the isName argument from true to false in the gotoLocalPage() method.

See the code snippet below.

```
public class MyCellEvent implements PdfPCellEvent {

    private String tableTitle;

    public void setTableTitle( String tableTitle ) {
        this.tableTitle = tableTitle;
    }    // end of method setTableTitle()

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte[] canvas) {
        PdfContentByte cb = canvas[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        boolean isName;
        float llx;
        float lly;
        float urx;
        float ury;
        PdfAction action = null;
        String destination;

        llx = rect.getLeft();
        lly = rect.getBottom();
        urx = rect.getRight();
        ury = rect.getTop();

        tableTitle = tableTitle.replace("_", " ");
        tableTitle = tableTitle.toUpperCase();

        destination =     "[" + LinkCreator.drawingNumber + "]_" + 
                "[COMPONENT]_" +
                "[" + tableTitle + "]_" +
                cell.getPhrase().toString();

        action = new PdfAction();
        isName = true;
        isName = false;
        action = PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(destination, isName);    // key method call
        cb.setAction(action, llx, lly, urx, ury);    // key method call

    }    // end of method cellLayout()

}    // end of class MyCellEvent}
```

Comment: If you don't show us the PDF, nobody will be able to answer your question. Some code would be nice too. If you're doing something wrong, we can't tell you what you're doing wrong without looking at your code.

Comment: this is a question about using the api.  we don't need the PDF.  code is now present